# IE Z-index not working with videojs

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, z-index, slideshow, html5-video

I have three absolute positioned divs

One for the Logo/menu link.
One for the Menu.
One for the page content.

I am using JQuery slidetoggle to hide/show the menu and have provided a high z-index for the menu div. I am using a JQuery slideshow for content in the content div. I am also using VideoJS to show a video on one of the pages in the content div.

All pages without VideoJS allow the z-indexed menu to show over the content div.

The problem I am having is the z-indexed menu will not show over the content div when it contains VideoJS in IE. It works fine in all other browsers.

I have uploaded these to the web. Could someone please help me figure out where my error is?

Comment: See this: http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: You are encouraged to provide code for the community to assist you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the caveat that I haven't had time to look at the code, this observation may be helpful:

In IE, an element cannot have a higher z-index than it's parent. So for instance, if you had this code:

```
<div id="container1" style="position:absolute;z-index:15">
   <div id="container1-child"  style="position:absolute;z-index:5"></div>
</div>

<div id="container2" style="position:absolute;z-index:5">
    <div id="container2-child" style="position:absolute;z-index:105"></div>
</div>
```

The div#container2-child will never have a z-index higher than 5 in IE, even though you set it to 105.